# How to capture the number value

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="minheight_row to_direction_cover">15</div>
```

How to save number 15 in variable.

I will will capture the existing value, than minus 1 and put back.

so 15 should become 14.

How can i do that.

thanks.

Comment: How many divs with the same class you have (it is important)?

Comment: What would be the best way to decrease the number by 1

Comment: These are very simple problems which have already been addressed on this site many times. Please try to do some research before posting questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

These are very beginner concepts, consider reading a javascript tutorial.

```js
var divElement = document.getElementsByClassName('minheight_row to_direction_cover')[0]; //Get html element
var value = +divElement.innerText; //access its value as string and with '+' cast it to number.
var newValue = value - 1; //increment or decrement
divElement.innerText = newValue; //set new value
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your div
2. Get the value with `innerText`
3. Decrement the value
4. Update your div with new value

   ```
   var myDiv = document.querySelector("minheight_row to_direction_cover");
   var value = myDiv.innerText;
   var newValue = value - 1;
   myDiv.innerText = newValue;
   ```

If you have more divs with this class, then definitely specify which one you intend, ex. `myDiv[0]`. See other answers also.

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('minheight_row to_direction_cover');
var value = elements[0].innerHTML;
var substracted = value - 1;
elements[0].innerHTML = substracted;
```

Comment: Do you mean `innerText`?

Comment: To me is does not matter in this case